# Is the Ahsoka novel still canon?

Tags: star-wars, canon, ahsoka-tano, tales-of-the-jedi

In the final episode of *Tales of the Jedi,* the story is very similar to the plotline of the 2016 *Ahsoka* novel.  I think Filoni did confirm that the episode is based on his original ideas for the novel.  And it wasn't explicitly said, but it is hinted that the Inquisitor that Ahsoka fights in TotJ is the same one she fought in the book.

The main difference between the show and the book is Ahsoka's involvement with Bail Organa and her choosing to join the Rebellion on a very different timeframe.  So - did this episode make the Ahsoka novel entirly non-canon?  Or is it possible for them to coexist?

Comment: One way to think about it is the "Tales of the Jedi" are retelling of these events.  Retelling of these kinds of events are not always 100% factually accurate but are good representations of what happened.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Thanks, that's not a bad interpretation.

Answer (score 6):

So far, the stance taken by Lucasfilm towards differences between adaptations has been that both works are broadly "true" (and remain Canon), but may differ in their details for dramatic purposes. No post-2014 Canon work that I'm aware of has been declared fully non-canon.

#### The *Ahsoka* novel vs. *The Clone Wars* Season 7

The 2016 *Ahsoka* novel included material based on the story outline for the [then-cancelled](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Clone_Wars_Legacy) "Siege of Mandalore" arc from *The Clone Wars*. However, when the [seventh season of *The Clone Wars*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Clone_Wars:_Season_Seven) was ultimately produced in 2020, there were [numerous differences](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Ahsoka_(novel)#The_Clone_Wars).

Lucasfilm Story Group's Matt Martin described the different accounts as "all work[ing] together", with neither version of events "any less valid":

> That's basically it. Things change during development, like the saber color, that doesn't effect the product as a whole any less valid. The sabers are blue now. The Pykes, as Jamie is saying, is not a contradiction. Things happen between SoD and the TCW eps.
>
> <sub>[Tweet by Matt Martin on 2020-04-17](https://twitter.com/missingwords/status/1251232918891945985)</sub>
>
> SoD and Ahsoka have elements that are based on TCW episodes that never finished their development. The new TCW episodes had the benefit of going through the full, standard, animation process. It's a unique situation but ultimately I believe they all work together.
>
> <sub>[Tweet by Matt Martin on 2020-04-17](https://twitter.com/missingwords/status/1251234974394548224)</sub>

"SoD" here is presumably [*Darth Maul: Son of Dathomir*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Darth_Maul%E2%80%94Son_of_Dathomir), another Canon adaptation of unproduced TCW scripts.

#### The *Kanan* comic vs. *The Bad Batch*

A 2015 comic showed the perspective of Kanan Jarrus (then Caleb Dume) during Order 66, but when the scene was revisited in the 2021 premiere of *The Bad Batch*, several details differed from the comic. Executive Producer Jennifer Corbett described the animated version as "another take" on the same events:

> Regarding those inconsistencies, Corbett said, “I can tell you that that particular sequence we spent the most time on in the pilot, from writing to production to editing to reshooting, because a lot of talk went into how we wanted to portray that pivotal moment with Dave Filoni and with Brad… Everything we did was for a reason and it might not match 100% but it’s sort of just wanting to honor what existed but also give another take on it in this story.”
>
> <sub>["‘The Bad Batch’ Creators Talk Omega, Familiar Star Wars Guests, and Canon Tweaks"](https://www.fandom.com/articles/bad-batch-star-wars-omega-jedi), article on Fandom</sub>

Lucasfilm's Story Group's Pablo Hidalgo weighed in with similar thoughts, although note that this is presented as one way to think about canon, and not necessarily Lucasfilm's official approach:

> If you want, one way to square this circle is the history textbook version of events “persons X and Y where on planet B when A occurred” is the canon; a fictional expression of it is potentially dramatized and embellished for its medium. Your space mileage may vary.
>
> <sub>[Tweet by Pablo Hidalgo on 2021-05-07](https://twitter.com/pabl0hidalgo/status/1390672907320258564)</sub>
>
> (This allows for the inevitable variations that must occur in transmedia adaptations of stories across formats.) okay, enough scholarship. It’s early.
>
> <sub>[Tweet by Pablo Hidalgo on 2021-05-07](https://twitter.com/pabl0hidalgo/status/1390673238376677382)</sub>

#### The *Ahsoka* novel vs. *Tales of the Jedi*

Getting back to the original question, Dave Filoni described the two versions of events as "the same story":

> *Tales of the Jedi* shows that Ahsoka makes different choices than Dooku, or even Anakin, at any number of points in her journey. “Resolve” particularly demonstrates Ahsoka’s resilience. We see her hiding among the crowd at her friend Padmé’s funeral and telling Bail she’s too weary to fight. Then she goes back on that decision after an Inquisitor burns down a village to find her. Ahsoka decides she cannot stand on the sidelines any longer.
>
> “I was doing these three pieces, one when she was very young, one that covers the formative years of the Clone Wars and her training, and I needed a piece that was somehow set after as a result of it. Playing with so much of her history as I have over the years, it was just natural to say, ‘Okay, well I’ll explain how she got back into this,'” Filoni explains, “It’s based on the same outline I gave publishing for the novel. It was always the same story.”
>
> <sub>["Dave Filoni on How TALES OF THE JEDI Explores Choices Between Light and Dark"](https://web.archive.org/web/20221026222129/https://nerdist.com/article/tales-of-the-jedi-dave-filoni-interview-ahsoka-tano-count-dooku-star-wars/), article on Nerdist</sub>

The novel's author, EK Johnston, agreed with the idea that these could be thought of as versions of the same story, rather than one being canon and the other not:

> There isn't a big conspiracy behind the changes in Ahsoka's story. Dave approved the book six years ago and then kept working on her journey. It's frustrating to see people gleefully declare my book non-canon instead of just...using their imaginations. Like we did.
>
> <sub>[Archived tweet by EK Johnston on 2022-07-31](https://archive.ph/YNtZn)</sub>

#### Conclusion

Given these precedents and the few statements we have by creators, it seems like the official stance is that the book's and show's broad strokes are both true, even if the way the details are presented varies by medium.

Comment: thanks! in hindsight, the first answer wasn't that far off, but the level of detail you provided is what I wanted to read.

Comment: I love your answer diving into even more than just my initial question - thanks so much for all this detail; I really appreciate it!

Answer (score -1):

Sadly the Disney timeline is fluid. But both are true, "from a certain point of view". The novel is primary to her connection in *Star Wars Rebels* and *The Mandalorian*, but for context was edited for *Tales of the Jedi*.

If allowed I would prefer the novel as I believe Dave Filoni hinted it is the missing piece between *Clone Wars* and *Rebels*. So the novel is more canon. To be fair both exist when viewed from the world between worlds, otherwise known as 'our' viewpoint. As suggested in comments here is a link https://comicbook.com/starwars/news/star-wars-ahsoka-series-2023-continuous-story-dave-filoni/. As stated in that title the events in and outside of the novel are connected. But also as stated above the Disney timeline is hard to predict. But as stated they are still connected.

Comment: You could improve this answer by editing it to include any relevant quotes from _Star Wars_ movies/shows or creators, such as Dave Filoni, and citing the exact source of each quote (i.e. the specific movie or episode, or the specific place where the creator made their statement/s).

Comment: I do love starwars but don't recall every detail. In honesty I said I believe because in media he has been quoted as saying the novel connects clone wars to rebels. My other points are again factual within starwars lore.

Comment: If you don't recall the precise source of the information you're referring to, then you should look it up, preferably before you post an answer, but in this case, so that you can add any relevant quotes and citations to this, existing answer. Providing specific evidence and citations is important in order to lend credibility to your answers, because otherwise, most of us won't know for sure if you're genuinely and accurately citing canon, or just making things up.